# How to restore a deleted task

Tags: tfs

I accidentally removed my tfs task NugetToolInstaller using tfx build task -delete command. And now I want to restore it. How can I do it?
I tried following this answer over here -> https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3768
But Then i get below error while running noe .\make.js build command:

```
> getting module externals
Downloading file: https://vstsagenttools.blob.core.windows.net/tools/NuGet/3.3.0/nuget.zip
C:\repos\vsts-tasks\node_modules\sync-request\index.js:37
    throw new Error(response.error.message || response.error || response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error. I edited my .npmrc file to point to our internal repository (Artifactory)also I changed the make.json file of this task to point to our Artifactory repo.

Answer (score 0):

TFS tasks for on-premise instance are stored in TFS file containers and it is not source controlled. So if it has been deleted I'm afraid there is no way to restore it back.

If you have the task in your local or if you are able to get it from some old build workspaces, you can upload it back.

Comment: The team had stored the tasks in our TFS repo already. But I see the tasks are source controlled here https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks. This should help I guess.